# How to get a path to some special folders in windows universal apps without "Enviroment"

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, special-folders

Usualy, to put some file to local directory on different devices (for example to mydocuments on some phone) we can get this directory using something like `environment.getfolderpath(environment.specialfolder.mydocuments)`. But if I am right, this wouldn't work in windows-universal application (may be because of x-box), enviroment got only `.GetEnviromentVariable(s)`.

So the question is - **how can we get a path to some local directory on any windows-device** (folders like mydocuments, applicationdata or the same, not temp or current directory or app-folder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `KnownFolders` class in `Windows.Storage` namespace.
For example, to access the `PictureLibrary` use:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
```

`StorageFolder` in its turn has a read-only property `Path`. By you should rethink the entire concept of manipulating files with the new API.

For example, to create an image file, you would use the following:

```
StorageFile file =
    await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.png",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

You can find more examples on MSDN: [KnownFolders class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx).

Comment: It's what I need! Thank you very much, so operatively!

Comment: How to get Desktop folder path?